# Issue - JUNIT verifying information added to Camel route header

Tags: junit, routes, apache-camel

I have a JUnit that will test my initialization route. It is a very simple method:

```
@Test
public void testInitializerRouteParams() throws Exception {

    String request = loadFile(SAMPLE_REQUEST_V1_XML);

    Map<String, Object> allHeaders = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    Object object = start.requestBody(ENDPOINT_URI, request);

    //assert code to check the route header is correct...

}
```

My route is something like:

```
<route id="initializer-route" startupOrder="92" shutdownRoute="Defer">
    <from uri="direct:initializer" />       
    <setHeader headerName="myFieldHeader">
        <xpath resultType="java.lang.String">//Find/context/myFied/text()</xpath>
    </setHeader>

    <!--other init info...-->           

</route>
```

My request/response is working. But I want on my response see if the information set on "myFieldHeader". I am not sure how to retrieve it.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to retrieve the header set on your "initializer" route, you can do it through the "Exchange" object that you receive as response.

For example:

```
exchange.getOut().getHeaders();
```

Or:

```
exchange.getOut().getHeader("myFieldHeader");
```

You can find more information here: http://camel.apache.org/using-getin-or-getout-methods-on-exchange.html

But if you want to check the content of the header inside your route, you could use Camel Simple Expression Language. (http://camel.apache.org/simple.html)

I hope it helps.

---

**Updated answer**

Probably you could use the ProducerTemplate.send() method and set the Exchange as "InOut" with the ExchangePattern. For example:

```
@Test
public void testInitializerRouteParams() throws Exception {

    String body = loadFile(SAMPLE_REQUEST_V1_XML);

    Exchange exchange = ExchangeBuilder.anExchange(camelContext)
                                       .withBody(body)
                                       .withPattern(ExchangePattern.InOut)
                                       .build();

    Exchange response = start.send(ENDPOINT_URI, exchange);

    //assert code to check the route header is correct...
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I've been using the exchange in other tests, but not this one. In the case above, for my testInitializerRouteParams() method, how can I retrieve the exchange?
Thank you again.

Comment: Hi, I have updated my answer with a possible solution.